# Presentation time of Audio buffer and Video buffer are not equal

Tags: swift, audio, avfoundation, audiounit, cmsamplebuffer

I'm trying to create an app that does live Video & Audio recording, using AVFoundation.
Also using AVAssetWriter I'm writing the buffers to a local file.

For the Video `CMSampleBuffer` I'm Using the `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` output in `AVCaptureSession` which is straightforward.

For the Audio `CMSampleBuffer` I'm creating the buffer from the AudioUnit record callback.
The way I'm calculating the presentation time for the Audio buffer is like so:

```
        var timebaseInfo = mach_timebase_info_data_t(numer: 0, denom: 0)
        let timebaseStatus = mach_timebase_info(&timebaseInfo)
        if timebaseStatus != KERN_SUCCESS {
            debugPrint("not working")
            return
        }
        let hostTime = time * UInt64(timebaseInfo.numer / timebaseInfo.denom)
        let presentationTIme = CMTime(value: CMTimeValue(hostTime), timescale: 1000000000)
        let duration = CMTime(value: CMTimeValue(1), timescale: CMTimeScale(self.sampleRate))

        var timing = CMSampleTimingInfo(
            duration: duration,
            presentationTimeStamp: presentationTIme,
            decodeTimeStamp: CMTime.invalid
        )
```

`self.sampleRate` is a variable that changes at the recording start, but most of the times is `48000`.

When getting the `CMSampleBuffers` of both the video and the audio the presentation times has a really big difference.

Audio - `CMTime(value: 981750843366125, timescale: 1000000000, flags: __C.CMTimeFlags(rawValue: 1), epoch: 0)`

Video - `CMTime(value: 997714237615541, timescale: 1000000000, flags: __C.CMTimeFlags(rawValue: 1), epoch: 0)`

This creates a big gap when trying to write the buffers to the file.

My questions is

1. Am I calculating the presentation Time of the audio buffer correctly? if so, what am I missing?
2. How can I make sure the Audio & the Video are in the same area of time (I know that there should be a small millisecond difference between them)

Comment: Aren't you getting truncation with `time * UInt64(timebaseInfo.numer / timebaseInfo.denom)`? Shouldn't that be `(time*numer)/denom`?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this was my fault.
As Rhythmic Fistman in the comments suggested, I was getting truncation with my time calculation:

`let hostTime = time * UInt64(timebaseInfo.numer / timebaseInfo.denom)`

Changing to this calculation fixed it

`let hostTime = (time * UInt64(timebaseInfo.numer)) / UInt64(timebaseInfo.denom)`